# Validation failed: Sender must exist, Recipient must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I am trying to create a message section on my website where users can send messages to other users from the user show page, but I keep on getting `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid in UsersController#show`

```
Validation failed: Sender must exist, Recipient must exist.
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here or how to even go about it,

I have a normal chat section that works well, and here are some code snippets from it.

Here is my conversations model

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :sender, foreign_key: :sender_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, foreign_key: :recipient_id, class_name: 'User'
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy
  validates_uniqueness_of :sender_id, scope: :recipient_id
  scope :between, -> (sender_id, recipient_id) do 
    where("(conversations.sender_id = ? AND   conversations.recipient_id =?) OR (conversations.sender_id = ? AND conversations.recipient_id =?)", sender_id, recipient_id, recipient_id, sender_id)
  end
end
```

And in the Message model, app/models/message.rb: I have

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :conversation
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :body, :conversation_id, :user_id
end
```

In the Conversations controller, app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb: I have

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @conversations = Conversation.all
  end
  def create  
    if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).present? 
       @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).first
    else
       @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
    end
    redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
  end
  private
  def conversation_params
    params.permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id)
  end
end
```

app/controllers/messages_controller.rb: I have

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action do
    @conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation_id])
  end
  
  def index
    @messages = @conversation.messages
    @message = @conversation.messages.new
  end
  def new
    @message = @conversation.messages.new
  end
  def create
    @message = @conversation.messages.new(message_params)
    if @message.save
      redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
    end
  end
  private
  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body, :user_id)
  end
end
```

In app/views/conversations/index.html.erb

```
<h1>My Inbox</h1>
<h1>All Conversations:</h1>
<% @conversations.each do |conversation| %>
 <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id || conversation.recipient_id == current_user.id %>
  <% if conversation.sender_id == current_user.id %>
   <% recipient = User.find(conversation.recipient_id) %>
  <% else %>
   <% recipient = User.find(conversation.sender_id) %>
  <% end %>
  <h3><%= link_to recipient.email, conversation_messages_path(conversation)%></h3>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
<h1>All Users:</h1>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
 <% if user.id != current_user.id %><h3>
 <%= link_to user.email, conversations_path(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: user.id), method: "post"%></h3>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In app/views/messages/index.html.erb I have

```
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
 <% if message.body %>
  <% user = User.find(message.user_id) %>
  <%= user.email %><%= message.message_time %>
  <%= message.body %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
<%= form_for [@conversation, @message] do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_area :body %>
 <%= f.text_field :user_id, value: current_user.id, type: "hidden" %>
 <%= f.submit "Send Reply" %>
<% end %>
```

This chat section works well, but now I want users to send messages by going to a particular user show page, click on send a message and it should take the user to the message page between the two users and users can chat with each other,

This is what I have tried

My User controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])

        if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).present? 
            @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).first
        else
            @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
        end
        redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
    end

    private
    def conversation_params
        params.permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id)
    end
end
```

My users/show.html.erb

```
<%#= link_to "Send Message", conversations_path(sender_id: current_user.id, recipient_id: teacher.id), method: "post"%></h3>
```

I am getting the error at the top when I try to run this, and I don't think I am doing this right; how do I let users message other users from a user show page?

Comment: Can you please share the log entry that shows the sent parameters when creating a new conversation?

Comment: This is my log
`Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "recipient_id"=>"5", "sender_id"=>"1"}
14:48:06 web.1     |   User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
14:48:06 web.1     |   Conversation Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "conversations".* FROM "conversations" WHERE ((conversations.sender_id = '1' AND   conversations.recipient_id ='5') OR (conversations.sender_id = '5' AND conversations.recipient_id ='1'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not rendering the template in UsersController#show. Try keeping it simple and let it render the show template, then you can use the link with `post` method to create conversation

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

Also `teacher` is not defined in your views, try replacing it with `@user`

Comment: This worked, thank you, I didn't see the teacher issue initially